# Creating multiple tables independent from each other JavaFX/Scenebuilder

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I am trying to build 3 different tables the will be be independent from each other. For some reason the cells are showing but are blank. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Main:
    package application;

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;


public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = (BorderPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("GUISCENEBUILDER.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,850,700);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.setTitle("Switch Utility");
            primaryStage.show();

        } catch(Exception e) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null,e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(Main.class, (java.lang.String[]) null);
    }
}
```

Product class: (Bad naming convention) (Going to change it to Press1)

```
package application;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

public class Product {
    private final SimpleStringProperty windowTime;

    public Product(String windowTimes) {
        this.windowTime = new SimpleStringProperty(windowTimes);
    }

    public String getwindowTime() {
        return windowTime.get();
    }

    public void setwindowTime(String newTime) {
        windowTime.set(newTime);
    }
```

Press2 class:

```
    package application;

    import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

    public class Press2 {
        private final SimpleStringProperty windowTime2;


        public Press2(String windowTimes2) {
                this.windowTime2 = new SimpleStringProperty(windowTimes2);
            }

            public String getwindowTime2() {
                return windowTime2.get();
            }

            public void setwindowTime2(String newTime) {
                windowTime2.set(newTime);
            }

    }
```

Press3:

```
package application;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

public class Press3 {
    private final SimpleStringProperty windowTime3;


    public Press3(String windowTimes3) {
            this.windowTime3 = new SimpleStringProperty(windowTimes3);
        }

        public String getwindowTime2() {
            return windowTime3.get();
        }

        public void setwindowTime2(String newTime) {
            windowTime3.set(newTime);
        }

}
```

TableViewController:

```
package application;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;

public class TableViewController implements Initializable {
    //Defining table
    @FXML
    private TableView<Product> tableID;

    @FXML
    private TableView<Press2> tableID2;

    @FXML
    private TableView<Press3> tableID3;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Product, String> windowTime;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Press2, String> windowTime2;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Press3, String> windowTime3;


    /*
     * Creating all the table data
     */
    final ObservableList<Product> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        new Product("7:00am - 8:30am"),
        new Product("10:00am - 11:10am"),
        new Product("12:00pm - 1:30pm"),
        new Product("3:00pm - 4:30pm")
    );
    final ObservableList<Press2> data2 = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        new Press2("8:00am - 8:30am"),
        new Press2("10:00am - 11:10am"),
        new Press2("12:00pm - 1:30pm"),
        new Press2("3:00pm - 4:30pm")
    );
    final ObservableList<Press3> data3 = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        new Press3("9:00am - 8:30am"),
        new Press3("10:00am - 11:10am"),
        new Press3("12:00pm - 1:30pm"),
        new Press3("3:00pm - 4:30pm")
    );

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class. This method is automatically called
     * after the fxml file has been loaded.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        windowTime.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Product, String>("windowTime"));
        windowTime2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Press2, String>("windowTime2"));
        windowTime3.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Press3, String>("windowTime3"));

        tableID.setItems(data);
        tableID2.setItems(data2);
        tableID3.setItems(data3);
    }

}
```

FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.Cursor?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Tab?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TabPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.InnerShadow?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.LinearGradient?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.Stop?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="700.0" prefWidth="850.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.TableViewController">
   <center>
      <TabPane prefHeight="472.0" prefWidth="850.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <tabs>
          <Tab text="Indigo">
            <content>
              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="526.0" prefWidth="805.0">
                     <children>
                        <ImageView fitHeight="559.0" fitWidth="850.0" layoutY="-7.0">
                           <image>
                              <Image url="@../../bin/application/1.jpg" />
                           </image>
                        </ImageView>
                        <TableView fx:id="tableID" layoutX="651.0" layoutY="44.0" prefHeight="237.0" prefWidth="134.0">
                           <columns>
                              <TableColumn fx:id="windowTime" prefWidth="75.0" text="Window Times" />
                           </columns>
                           <columnResizePolicy>
                              <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
                           </columnResizePolicy>
                        </TableView>
                        <TextField layoutX="14.0" layoutY="55.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="475.0" promptText="C:\Users\ASUprint\Desktop\Enfocus\Switch\ASU Print Online\Output\Ready for Print" />
                        <Button layoutX="501.0" layoutY="55.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="77.0" text="Browse" />
                        <TextField layoutX="14.0" layoutY="87.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="475.0" promptText="J:\CMYK+Spot" />
                        <Button layoutX="501.0" layoutY="87.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="77.0" text="Browse" />
                        <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="21.0" text="Connection 1:" underline="true">
                           <font>
                              <Font name="Lucida Sans Demibold" size="20.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Label>
                        <TextField layoutX="14.0" layoutY="166.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="475.0" promptText="C:\Users\ASUprint\Desktop\Enfocus\Switch\ASU Print Online\Output\Ready for Print" />
                        <Button layoutX="501.0" layoutY="166.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="77.0" text="Browse" />
                        <TextField layoutX="14.0" layoutY="198.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="475.0" promptText="J:\CMYK+Spot" />
                        <Button layoutX="501.0" layoutY="198.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="77.0" text="Browse" />
                        <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="132.0" text="Connection 2:" underline="true">
                           <font>
                              <Font name="Lucida Sans Demibold" size="20.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Label>
                        <TextField layoutX="14.0" layoutY="276.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="475.0" promptText="C:\Users\ASUprint\Desktop\Enfocus\Switch\ASU Print Online\Output\Ready for Print" />
                        <Button layoutX="501.0" layoutY="276.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="77.0" text="Browse" />
                        <TextField layoutX="14.0" layoutY="308.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="475.0" promptText="J:\CMYK+Spot" />
                        <Button layoutX="501.0" layoutY="308.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="77.0" text="Browse" />
                        <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="242.0" text="Connection 3:" underline="true">
                           <font>
                              <Font name="Lucida Sans Demibold" size="20.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Label>
                        <TextField layoutX="14.0" layoutY="387.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="475.0" promptText="C:\Users\ASUprint\Desktop\Enfocus\Switch\ASU Print Online\Output\Ready for Print" />
                        <Button layoutX="501.0" layoutY="387.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="77.0" text="Browse" />
                        <TextField layoutX="14.0" layoutY="419.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="475.0" promptText="J:\CMYK+Spot" />
                        <Button layoutX="501.0" layoutY="419.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="77.0" text="Browse" />
                        <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="353.0" text="Connection 4:" underline="true">
                           <font>
                              <Font name="Lucida Sans Demibold" size="20.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Label>
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
            </content>
          </Tab>
          <Tab text="iGen">
            <content>
              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                     <children>
                        <ImageView fitHeight="561.0" fitWidth="850.0" layoutY="-7.0">
                           <image>
                              <Image url="@../../bin/application/1.jpg" />
                           </image>
                        </ImageView>
                        <TableView fx:id="tableID2" layoutX="651.0" layoutY="44.0" prefHeight="237.0" prefWidth="134.0">
                           <columns>
                              <TableColumn fx:id="windowTime2" prefWidth="75.0" text="Window Times" />
                           </columns>
                           <columnResizePolicy>
                              <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
                           </columnResizePolicy>
                        </TableView>
                        <TextField layoutX="14.0" layoutY="55.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="475.0" promptText="C:\Users\ASUprint\Desktop\Enfocus\Switch\ASU Print Online\Envelopes\10x13 for Press" />
                        <Button layoutX="501.0" layoutY="55.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="77.0" text="Browse" />
                        <TextField layoutX="14.0" layoutY="87.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="475.0" promptText="J:\10 x 13 Envelopes" />
                        <Button layoutX="501.0" layoutY="87.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="77.0" text="Browse" />
                        <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="21.0" text="Connection 1:" underline="true">
                           <font>
                              <Font name="Lucida Sans Demibold" size="20.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Label>
                        <TextField layoutX="14.0" layoutY="166.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="475.0" promptText="C:\Users\ASUprint\Desktop\Enfocus\Switch\ASU Print Online\Envelopes\10x13 for Press" />
                        <Button layoutX="501.0" layoutY="166.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="77.0" text="Browse" />
                        <TextField layoutX="14.0" layoutY="198.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="475.0" promptText="J:\10 x 13 Envelopes" />
                        <Button layoutX="501.0" layoutY="198.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="77.0" text="Browse" />
                        <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="132.0" text="Connection 2:" underline="true">
                           <font>
                              <Font name="Lucida Sans Demibold" size="20.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Label>
                        <TextField layoutX="14.0" layoutY="276.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="475.0" promptText="C:\Users\ASUprint\Desktop\Enfocus\Switch\ASU Print Online\Envelopes\10x13 for Press" />
                        <Button layoutX="501.0" layoutY="276.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="77.0" text="Browse" />
                        <TextField layoutX="14.0" layoutY="308.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="475.0" promptText="J:\10 x 13 Envelopes" />
                        <Button layoutX="501.0" layoutY="308.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="77.0" text="Browse" />
                        <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="242.0" text="Connection 3:" underline="true">
                           <font>
                              <Font name="Lucida Sans Demibold" size="20.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Label>
                        <TextField layoutX="14.0" layoutY="387.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="475.0" promptText="C:\Users\ASUprint\Desktop\Enfocus\Switch\ASU Print Online\Envelopes\10x13 for Press" />
                        <Button layoutX="501.0" layoutY="387.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="77.0" text="Browse" />
                        <TextField layoutX="14.0" layoutY="419.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="475.0" promptText="J:\10 x 13 Envelopes" />
                        <Button layoutX="501.0" layoutY="419.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="77.0" text="Browse" />
                        <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="353.0" text="Connection 4:" underline="true">
                           <font>
                              <Font name="Lucida Sans Demibold" size="20.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Label>
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
            </content>
          </Tab>
             <Tab text="Memjet">
              <content>
                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                     <children>
                        <ImageView fitHeight="559.0" fitWidth="850.0" layoutY="-7.0">
                           <image>
                              <Image url="@../../bin/application/1.jpg" />
                           </image>
                        </ImageView>
                        <TableView fx:id="tableID3" layoutX="651.0" layoutY="44.0" prefHeight="237.0" prefWidth="134.0">
                          <columns>
                            <TableColumn fx:id="windowTime3" prefWidth="75.0" text="Window Times" />
                          </columns>
                           <columnResizePolicy>
                              <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
                           </columnResizePolicy>
                        </TableView>
                        <TextField layoutX="14.0" layoutY="55.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="475.0" promptText="C:\Users\ASUprint\Desktop\Enfocus\Switch\ASU Print Online\Envelopes\10x13 for Press" />
                        <Button layoutX="501.0" layoutY="55.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="77.0" text="Browse" />
                        <TextField layoutX="14.0" layoutY="87.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="475.0" promptText="A:\" />
                        <Button layoutX="501.0" layoutY="87.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="77.0" text="Browse" />
                        <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="21.0" text="Connection 1:" underline="true">
                           <font>
                              <Font name="Lucida Sans Demibold" size="20.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Label>
                        <TextField layoutX="14.0" layoutY="166.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="475.0" promptText="C:\Users\ASUprint\Desktop\Enfocus\Switch\ASU Print Online\Envelopes\10x13 for Press" />
                        <Button layoutX="501.0" layoutY="166.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="77.0" text="Browse" />
                        <TextField layoutX="14.0" layoutY="198.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="475.0" promptText="A:\" />
                        <Button layoutX="501.0" layoutY="198.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="77.0" text="Browse" />
                        <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="132.0" text="Connection 2:" underline="true">
                           <font>
                              <Font name="Lucida Sans Demibold" size="20.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Label>
                        <TextField layoutX="14.0" layoutY="276.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="475.0" promptText="C:\Users\ASUprint\Desktop\Enfocus\Switch\ASU Print Online\Envelopes\10x13 for Press" />
                        <Button layoutX="501.0" layoutY="276.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="77.0" text="Browse" />
                        <TextField layoutX="14.0" layoutY="308.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="475.0" promptText="J:\10 x 13 Envelopes" />
                        <Button layoutX="501.0" layoutY="308.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="77.0" text="Browse" />
                        <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="242.0" text="Connection 3:" underline="true">
                           <font>
                              <Font name="Lucida Sans Demibold" size="20.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Label>
                        <TextField layoutX="14.0" layoutY="387.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="475.0" promptText="C:\Users\ASUprint\Desktop\Enfocus\Switch\ASU Print Online\Envelopes\10x13 for Press" />
                        <Button layoutX="501.0" layoutY="387.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="77.0" text="Browse" />
                        <TextField layoutX="14.0" layoutY="419.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="475.0" promptText="A:\" />
                        <Button layoutX="501.0" layoutY="419.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="77.0" text="Browse" />
                        <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="353.0" text="Connection 4:" underline="true">
                           <font>
                              <Font name="Lucida Sans Demibold" size="20.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Label>
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
              </content>
            </Tab>
        </tabs>
      </TabPane>
   </center>
   <top>
      <Pane prefHeight="126.0" prefWidth="850.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <ImageView fitHeight="126.0" fitWidth="850.0">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@../../bin/application/1.1.jpg" />
               </image>
            </ImageView>
            <Button layoutX="489.0" layoutY="23.0" mnemonicParsing="false" style="-fx-background-color: #C9CED9;" text="Start">
               <font>
                  <Font size="38.0" />
               </font>
               <effect>
                  <InnerShadow blurType="ONE_PASS_BOX" color="WHITE" height="27.06" radius="6.265" width="0.0">
                     <input>
                        <DropShadow blurType="TWO_PASS_BOX" />
                     </input></InnerShadow>
               </effect>
               <cursor>
                  <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
               </cursor>
               <textFill>
                  <LinearGradient cycleMethod="REFLECT" endX="0.8523809523809524" startX="0.8333333333333334" startY="0.5523809523809524">
                     <stops>
                        <Stop color="#0a9e3b" />
                        <Stop color="#455445" offset="0.9961685823754789" />
                        <Stop color="#455445" offset="1.0" />
                     </stops>
                  </LinearGradient>
               </textFill>
            </Button>
            <Button depthTest="ENABLE" layoutX="639.0" layoutY="23.0" mnemonicParsing="false" style="-fx-background-color: #C9CED9;" text="Stop">
               <font>
                  <Font size="38.0" />
               </font>
               <effect>
                  <InnerShadow blurType="ONE_PASS_BOX" color="WHITE" height="27.06" radius="6.265" width="0.0">
                     <input>
                        <DropShadow blurType="TWO_PASS_BOX" />
                     </input></InnerShadow>
               </effect>
               <cursor>
                  <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
               </cursor>
               <textFill>
                  <LinearGradient cycleMethod="REFLECT" endX="0.8523809523809524" startX="0.8333333333333334" startY="0.5523809523809524">
                     <stops>
                        <Stop color="#c33838" />
                        <Stop color="#455445" offset="0.9961685823754789" />
                        <Stop color="#455445" offset="1.0" />
                     </stops>
                  </LinearGradient>
               </textFill>
            </Button>
            <ImageView fitHeight="118.0" fitWidth="300.0" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="5.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@../../bin/application/ASU_PrintImagingLab_Horiz_RGB_MaroonGold_150ppi.png" />
               </image>
            </ImageView>
         </children>
         <cursor>
            <Cursor fx:constant="DEFAULT" />
         </cursor>
      </Pane>
   </top>
</BorderPane>
```

Comment: Not related to error, but: Why do you need three different model classes: they are identical apart from the name.? Why don't you use the same model class for all three tables?

Comment: Well my goal is to make it so each table can be updated independently so I figured to make them separate classes. Im new to Java so my understanding of getters and setters and how to implement them in code is hard for me to understand. I read through the duplicated questions and I now understand it has something to do with PropertyValueFactory. Still trying to figure it out

Comment: Why would using the same model prevent them being updated independently? They will still have different instances of those classes in their items list. As for the actual question, just read the answers to the linked questions: it is not complicated. `new PropertyValueFactory<>("windowTime")` means the column will first look for a `windowTimeProperty()` method returning a `StringProperty`: if it can't find it, it will look for a `getWindowTime()` method returning a `String`. You don't have either of those.

Comment: Oh... Its starting to make more sense to me. Camel Case does matter i forgot about that. It works now thank you for your reply and explanation!